# how does wireshark recognize the protocal on the application level?

Tags: wireshark-dissector

I want to write an  app to capture the packets of S7comm，but it seems that the S7comm protocal does not have a well konwn port.So how can I recognize the packets of S7Comm?

Answer (score 0):

Write a [heuristic dissector](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Lua/Examples) in Wireshark to recognize it. Use info from [WS-Wiki-S7comm](https://wiki.wireshark.org/S7comm), e.g. you know the 1st byte is 0x32, redundancy indicator seems to be always 0x0000 (2 bytes, the 3rd and 4th), possible length values etc.